# Create Custom JSON STRING

Tags: ios, json

I want to send a data to server using JSON string. The following is the format of JSON object I want to use. Please help me to create this type of structure.

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.MetrolinkVerificationListItem' },
                    'Company': 'SOCALGAS-15',
                    'Date': '08/31/2016',
                    'Employee_x0020_ID': '545',
                    'Month': 'JULY',
                    'Name_x0020_of_x0020_Transit': 'METROLINK',
                    'Total_x0020_Amount_x0020_Spent': '444',
                    'Year': '2015'}
```

Comment: can you show your tried code

Comment: and what the issue u faced

Comment: NSDictionary *dict1=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"SP.Data.MetrolinkVerificationListItem",@"type",nil];
    
    NSDictionary *dict2=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"hai",@"name",@"1234",@"pas",nil];
    
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  dict2,@"device",dict1,@"metadata",nil];
   

    NSString *str=[myDictionary bv_jsonStringWithPrettyPrint:NO];

       NSLog(@"json string %@",str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to pass the `NSDictionary` as param on your request use this

```
NSDictionary *type = @{ @"type" : @"SP.Data.MetrolinkVerification‌​ListItem"
                       };

NSDictionary *final = @{@"metadata" : type, @"pas" : @"1234",@"name" : @"hai"
                       };

NSLog(@"json string %@",final);
```

**output**

[image]

if you want to pass the `NSDictionary`  to `JSON String` as param on your request use this

```
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:final
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSLog(@"final %@",jsonString);
}
```

**output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSString's `stringWithFormat`:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ '__metadata': { 'type': '%@' },'Company': '%@','Date': '%@','Employee_x0020_ID': '%@','Month': '%@','Name_x0020_of_x0020_Transit': '%@','Total_x0020_Amount_x0020_Spent': '%@','Year': '%@'}",typeStr,companyStr,dateStr,employeeIDStr,monthStr,nameTransitStr,amountSpentStr,yearStr];
```

If you want to replace string with an NSInteger replace the %@ with %ld